# Receive message with a custom object on Android SignalR client, data isn't deserializing

Tags: java, android, asp.net-core-signalr, signalr-client

I'm using SignalR on ASP.NET Core 5 web server for Android device management. I can send messages from device (D2C), and receive messages with `String` parameters (C2D). But I can't receive messages with custom object parameters, the handler receives all object members as null. I develop an WPF client and it receives this object well.

I'm following [ASP.NET Core SignalR Java client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0) documentation. It explains how to use custom objects in [Passing Class information in Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0#passing-class-information-in-java) section.

In build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.microsoft.signalr:signalr:5.0.5'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-jdk14:1.7.25'
}
```

This is my custom class in Android project:

```
package com.mycompany.mayapp.signalr.models;

public class CustomClass
{
    public String Param1;
    public String Param2;
}
```

If this can help, this is my custom class in ASP.NET Core project (if I use fields instead of properties WPF client doesn't work, I don't know why):

```
namespace MyWebWithSignalRCore.SignalR.Models
{
    public class CustomClass
    {
        public string Param1 { get; set; }
        public string Param2 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And this is my android client class:

```
package com.mycompany.mayapp.signalr;

import android.util.Log;
import com.fagorelectronica.fagorconnectservice.signalr.models.UpdateAppParams;
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnection;
import com.microsoft.signalr.HubConnectionBuilder;
import com.microsoft.signalr.OnClosedCallback;
import com.microsoft.signalr.TypeReference;    
import java.lang.reflect.Type;

public class SignalRClient
{
    private static final String TAG = SignalRClient.class.getSimpleName();
    HubConnection hubConnection;

    public SignalRClient(String url)
    {
        this.hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder.create(url).build();
        this.handleIncomingMethods();
    }
    private void handleIncomingMethods()
    {
        this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (user, message) -> { // OK
            Log.d(TAG, user + ": " + message);
        }, String.class, String.class);

        this.hubConnection.on("Reset", () -> { // OK
            Log.d(TAG, "Reset device");
        });

        Type customClassType = new TypeReference<CustomClass>() { }.getType();
        this.hubConnection.<CustomClass>on("Custom", (params) -> { // NOK!!
            Log.d(TAG, params.Param1 + ": " + params.Param2);
        }, customClassType);
    }

    public void start()
    {
        this.hubConnection.start().blockingAwait();
        this.hubConnection.send("Hello", "My device ID"); // OK
    }
    public void stop()
    {
        this.hubConnection.stop().blockingAwait();
    }    
}
```

This is the output I get in each handler:

```
D/SignalRClient: User: message
D/SignalRClient: Reset device
D/SignalRClient: null: null
```

Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that in the java client the custom object field names should be in lowercase. So changing the field names solves the problem.

Custom class in Android project:

```
package com.mycompany.mayapp.signalr.models;

public class CustomClass
{
    public String param1;
    public String param2;
}
```

Handling method:

```
private void handleIncomingMethods()
{
    // ... other methods ...

    Type customClassType = new TypeReference<CustomClass>() { }.getType();
    this.hubConnection.<CustomClass>on("Custom", (params) -> { // OK!!
        Log.d(TAG, params.param1 + ": " + params.param2);
    }, customClassType);
}
```